# Where to ask for the best webhosting services?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking to find a decent web hosting service but when I posted a question asking for just that on Stack Overflow, I got shut down by a bunch of users that closed my question due to it not being programming-related. Which of the other sites would it be better for me to post this question on? And if it belongs on none of the others, why am I getting denied? The one answer was pretty good, but I'd like more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the SO family goes, I guess that would be either Super User or Server Fault.

**But wait**; before you ask another question *anywhere*, you might want to check out the following, because several very similar questions have already been asked:

- [Highest voted 'web-hosting' questions on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=web-hosting&sort=votes&pagesize=15)
- [Highest voted 'web-hosting' questions on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=web-hosting&sort=votes&pagesize=15)

Comment: Answering based on valid data. What do you think where you are?

Comment: Thanks Jonik, even better than what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

Even though this is an old question, it should be noted that polling for things like "What is the best webhost" or "Where should I buy hosting" are off-topic across the *entire* network now. This absolutely includes Server Fault and Super User.

Comment: _This_ should be the accepted answer. But, of course, the OP is long gone. Perhaps this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's a very subjective question. Anything "Best" of something is highly subjective. So I would suggest rewording it.

Stackoverflow is for programming related items. You could try to look at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Also look at these questions about subjective questions.

- [Do we really need the “subjective” tag and is it commonly mis-used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19113/do-we-really-need-the-subjective-tag-and-is-it-commonly-mis-used)
- [Super User attracting too many open-ended/subjective questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5766/super-user-attracting-too-many-open-ended-subjective-questions)

Answer (score 0):

For webhosting stories and comparison, none of SOFU.

Instead, give it a shot at [Web Hosting Talk](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/)

Answer (score -5):

[ServerFault](http://ServerFault.com)

That is the StackExchange website related to all things Server/Hardware related.

Comment: I wouldn't say that ServerFault, since he's not managing the webserver. But he wants to buy a webhosting service.

Comment: But the people at ServerFault would be the experts to ask.

Comment: The appropriate answer to this question these days is [Nowhere](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)